# JAVA FX - How can I remove an object from a pane?

Tags: java, fxml

I'm trying to add a project with java fx. On this project I have a stack pane containing an AnchorPane with all the controls, and an empty VBox on top.

When I perform call to a remote API, which will take a while to respond, I load a ProgressIndicator on the VBox. That works ok, but at the moment I get the answer from the API, I try to remove the ProgressIndicator from the VBox, and I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = OkHttp http://api.kiwandafood.betas.bolboretapps.com/...
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:444)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:221)
    at com.kiwandalabs.forklift.view.MainOverviewController.setLoading(MainOverviewController.java:536)
    at com.kiwandalabs.forklift.model.Cloud$3.onResponse(Cloud.java:223)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is the code where I'm getting the exception, at the line where I remove the ProgressIndicator from the VBox:

```
public void setLoading(boolean set) {
        if (set) {
            //Activar
            pi = new ProgressIndicator();
            loadingBox.getChildren().add(pi);
            layoutPrincipal.setDisable(true);
            //System.out.println(stackPrincipal.getChildren().indexOf(loadingBox));
        }else {
            //Desactivar
            layoutPrincipal.setDisable(false);
            loadingBox.getChildren().remove(pi);
            pi = null;
        }
} //End setLoading
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the action(s) on the FX Application Thread e.g.

```
javafx.application.Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
    //  TODO: update UI components here
});
```

**Edit**:
Also, my guess would be, when adding the progress indicator, you are in the appropriate thread.

Comment: Mmm, yes, that maybe has sense. When I call the function the first time, I'm in the main thread, but when I call the function the second time, in order to remove the ProgressIndicator, I'm calling from a function callback implemented in a different Thread for API communication. Thank you for the answer!